# VLC fullscreen on Display3 run from CMD

Tags: vlc

I'm using Windows 10 Pro latest build, and latest VLC media player 3.0.12 Vetinari.
I checked vlc docs but either I didn't understand it correctly, or it simply doesn't work properly.

I have 4 screens connected, most of which have different resolutions (different size monitors).

I'm trying to create a batch file to open vlc in fullscreen mode, specifically on Display3.
I have tried:
`path\to\vlc.exe "path\to\myvideo.mp4" --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY3" --fullscreen`
this did fullscreen, however it was not on DISPLAY3 it was on DISPLAY1, I even tried to play it on DISPLAY2, it still went to DISPLAY1, i tried it on DISPLAY4 and still same problem.

I also tried:
`path\to\vlc.exe "path\to\myvideo.mp4" --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=3`
this did the same thing as first command I tried.

Pretty much all I'm after is to display a video on the 3rd monitor \.\DISPLAY3, which will have fullscreen, no audio, no controls, no name of video files displayed, forever loop

your help is greatly appreciated